# Ordenar lista sin paginar en php laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

Estoy organizando unos objectos de lista por sus nombres, pero quiero ordenarlos sin necesidad de tener que paginarlos. El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
if ($filter['sort'] == 'name_asc'){
    return Employee::orderBy('first_name', 'ASC')->paginate(1000);
} else if ($filter['sort'] == 'name_desc') {
    return Employee::orderBy('first_name', 'DESC')->paginate(1000);
}
```

Pero yo quiero retornar los Employee sin necesidad del metodo (paginate). como podria resolverlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para traer los los registros sin paginación simplemente utiliza el método `get()`:

```
Employee::orderBy('first_name', 'ASC')->get();
```

Puedes revisar la documentación aquí:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#retrieving-results

Comment: Eso era lo que estaba buscando, pero no lo recordaba. Muchisimas gracias